# Adding Conditions to the Listboxes from .csv files

Tags: vb.net, csv, drag-and-drop, compare, listboxitem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baPMO.png)i am looking for this problem for very long time and I have found nothing about that... :( .
So, I have 2 .csv files. In the .csv file 1 are the listboxes and all of these listboxes have one number between 1 and 6. In the .csv file 2 are some tools like (audi, bmw) and the tools have one numer between 1 and 6 too.

Example:

.csv file 1

Listbox 1 (X,Y,Length,Width)  category   1

Listbox 2 (X,Y,Length,Width)  category   2

Listbox 3 (X,Y,Length,Width)  category   3

---

.csv file 2

Mercedes category 1

BMW      category 2

Audi     category 3

So, I want compare the 2 .csv files and allow the listbox 2 for only BMW to drag and drop.
If I drop categroy 2 to category 1 in the listbox, it should be false.

---

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2

    Private meineListBoxen As New List(Of ListBox)


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strZeilen() As String
        Dim strFelder() As String
        Dim strZeilen0() As String
        Dim strZeilen2() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Datenerfassung.csv")
        Dim strFelder1() As String
        strZeilen = File.ReadAllLines("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\listboxpflege.csv")
        strZeilen0 = IO.File.ReadAllLines("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Spritzguss.csv")

        For i As Integer = 1 To strZeilen.GetUpperBound(0)
            strFelder = strZeilen(i).Split(";")

            meineListBoxen.Add(New ListBox)

            With meineListBoxen(i - 1)
                .Left = strFelder(0)
                .Top = strFelder(1)
                .Width = strFelder(2)
                .Height = strFelder(3)
            End With

            Me.Controls.Add(meineListBoxen(i - 1))
            Me.meineListBoxen(i - 1).AllowDrop = True
            AddHandler meineListBoxen(i - 1).MouseDown, AddressOf meineListbox_MouseDown
            AddHandler meineListBoxen(i - 1).DragDrop, AddressOf meineListbox_DragDrop
            AddHandler meineListBoxen(i - 1).DragEnter, AddressOf meineListbox_DragEnter
        Next
        For a As Integer = 0 To strZeilen0.GetUpperBound(0)
            Me.meineListBoxen(1 - 1).Items.Add(strZeilen0(a).Substring(0, strZeilen0(a).IndexOf(";")))
        Next
        For j As Integer = 1 To strZeilen2.GetUpperBound(0)
            strFelder1 = strZeilen2(j).Split(" ")

            With meineListBoxen(j)
                .Items.Add(strFelder1(4))

            End With
            For Each itm In meineListBoxen(j).Items
                If meineListBoxen(1 - 1).Items.Contains(itm) Then meineListBoxen(1 - 1).Items.Remove(itm)
            Next
        Next


    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        Me.lblMaus.Text = "X: " & e.X & " , Y:" & e.Y
    End Sub


    Private source As ListBox
    Private sourceIndex As Integer

    Private Sub meineListbox_MouseDown(ByVal sendre As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Dim aPoint As Point
        Dim lbx As ListBox
        Dim aIndex As Integer

        lbx = CType(sendre, ListBox)
        aPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        aIndex = lbx.IndexFromPoint(aPoint)
        Try
            If aIndex <= 0 Then
                source = lbx
                sourceIndex = aIndex
                lbx.DoDragDrop(lbx.Items(aIndex), DragDropEffects.All)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte wählen Sie ein Werkzeug aus")
        End Try



    End Sub
    Private Sub meineListbox_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object,
      ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)

        Dim lbx As ListBox

        lbx = CType(sender, ListBox)
        If Not source Is Nothing Then
            source.Items.RemoveAt(sourceIndex)
        End If
        lbx.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text))
    End Sub



    Private Sub meineListbox_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object,
      ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)

        If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Speichern.Click
        Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Datenerfassung.csv")

        For i = 0 To meineListBoxen.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(meineListBoxen.Item(i))

        Next
        w.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub WerkzeugHinzufügen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WerkzeugHinzufügen.Click
        Process.Start("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Spritzguss.csv")
    End Sub

    Private Sub StellplatzHinzufügen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StellplatzHinzufügen.Click
        Process.Start("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\listboxpflege.csv")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: csv stands for comma separated values. The contents of the files that you show do not seem to follow this pattern. Have you accurately shown the contents of the files?

Comment: The very first thing you need to do is turn on Option Strict in Project Properties. Also set it On in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VB Defaults.

Comment: `If aIndex <= 0 Then` The index of the first item in the ListBox is index 0.

Comment: Do the 2 `Process.Start` methods work?

Comment: What we need is a minimal, complete, and reproducible  presentation for your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Speichern.Click
    Using w As New StreamWriter("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Datenerfassung.csv")
        For i = 0 To meineListBoxen.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(meineListBoxen.Item(i))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

I find it odd that the Handles clause does not match the name of the method. The default would be Private Sub Speichern_Click

StreamWriter needs to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will handle this even if there is an error.

Let's say you have 3 list boxes. Your loop will go from index 0 to index 2. `WriteLine` will call `ToString` on each item in the list of `ListBox`. I don't believe that a `ListBox` provides an implementation of `ToString` so you will get the fully qualified name of the object's type. I don't think you want this.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Speichern.Click
    Using w As New StreamWriter("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Datenerfassung.csv")
        For Each LB As ListBox In meineListBoxen
            For Each item As String In LB.Items
                w.WriteLine(item)
            Next
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

You can initialize your variables as you declare them and with Option Infer they will be strongly typed (only works for local variables.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim strZeilen2 = File.ReadAllLines("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Datenerfassung.csv")
    Dim strZeilen = File.ReadAllLines("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\listboxpflege.csv")
    Dim strZeilen0 = File.ReadAllLines("K:\Ruebel_Andreas\Modellpflege\Spritzguss.csv")
    For i = 1 To strZeilen.GetUpperBound(0) 'Why are skipping the first line?
        Dim strFelder = strZeilen(i).Split(";"c)
        Dim LB As New ListBox
        With LB
            .Left = CInt(strFelder(0))
            .Top = CInt(strFelder(1))
            .Width = CInt(strFelder(2))
            .Height = CInt(strFelder(3))
            .AllowDrop = True
            .Name = "ListBox" & i 'In case you need to refer to the control be name
        End With
        If i = 1 Then
            For a As Integer = 0 To strZeilen0.GetUpperBound(0)
                LB.Items.Add(strZeilen0(a).Substring(0, strZeilen0(a).IndexOf(";")))
            Next
        End If
        AddHandler LB.MouseDown, AddressOf meineListbox_MouseDown
        AddHandler LB.DragDrop, AddressOf meineListbox_DragDrop
        AddHandler LB.DragEnter, AddressOf meineListbox_DragEnter
        'I fleshed out the control before adding to the collections
        Controls.Add(LB)
        meineListBoxen.Add(LB)
    Next
    For j = 1 To strZeilen2.GetUpperBound(0) 'Again skipping first line, perhaps it is a title line
        Dim strFelder1 = strZeilen2(j).Split(" "c)
        meineListBoxen(j).Items.Add(strFelder1(4)) 'You are skipping the first list box
        For Each itm In meineListBoxen(j).Items
            If meineListBoxen(0).Items.Contains(itm) Then
                meineListBoxen(0).Items.Remove(itm)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

No need to define a point, just pass the coordinates to the `IndexFromPoint` method. You can use `DirectCast` to get the `ListBox` since we are sure the `sender` is a `ListBox`. `DirectCast` skips some of the checks that `CType` does so the method so is a bit faster. I am not sure if the check on the value of `aIndex` is necessary. `Exception` handling is heavy and shouldn't be used for a simple value check.

```
Private Sub meineListbox_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim lbx = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    Dim aIndex = lbx.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)

    If aIndex < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte wählen Sie ein Werkzeug aus")
    Else
        source = lbx
        sourceIndex = aIndex
        lbx.DoDragDrop(lbx.Items(aIndex), DragDropEffects.All)
    End If
End Sub
```

Use `IsNot` when checking for null objects.

```
Private Sub meineListbox_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    Dim lbx = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    If source IsNot Nothing Then
        source.Items.RemoveAt(sourceIndex)
    End If
    lbx.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text))
End Sub
```

Updating this label over and over will just slow things down. Delete this Sub.

```
'Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    'lblMaus.Text = "X: " & e.X & " , Y: " & e.Y
'End Sub
```

I can't help more without correct data from your files. At one point, you are splitting by a semicolon and there aren't any in your sample data! The file content you showed is certainly not a CSV file.